Trigger animation not playing due to transition or something in Unity
I’ve set up an animation trigger (Any State -> Fire) to interrupt all other animations, and it works as expected most of the time. However, I’ve run into an issue where, if the Animator is in the middle of a state transition, the trigger doesn’t interrupt the transition, and the Fire animation doesn’t play immediately.


I’ve already done the following:

Disabled Has Exit Time for the transition to Fire.
Set Interruption Source to Current State.
Reduced the Transition Duration to 0.
Despite these settings, if another animation is transitioning when I activate the trigger, the Fire animation is delayed until the transition completes.

How can I ensure that the Fire animation immediately interrupts any ongoing transitions, regardless of their current state?

Could you record a video of the event or share the project for testing on github?
